# Internal Server Error with Cakephp 2.1.1 happens extremely often

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, mod-rewrite

Cakephp 2.1.1 app is creating a lot of internal server errors. Whenever I restart apache it starts working again but goes down after a little while.

below is what I am getting on error log.

```
2012-04-13 13:13:52 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class GController could not be found.
#0 /home/commstrat2_web/html/roadconference/app/webroot/index.php(96): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
```

Can anyone figure out why?

**UPDATE: Below is the error from the site that is very similar and has been copied across but different error from the log**

```
2012-04-13 12:57:27 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class AssetsController could not be found.
#0 /home/commstrat2_web/html/nbnsummit/app/webroot/index.php(96): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2012-04-13 12:57:27 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class ImagesController could not be found.
#0 /home/commstrat2_web/html/nbnsummit/app/webroot/index.php(96): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
```

Comment: *Should* that controller exist? Are you just seeing those errors in the log, or first hand when navigating to a URL?

Comment: Hey Deceze! Nice to talk again. This error is from log. There's also another two more errors from another Cake site on same server with extremely similar settings as I have pretty much copied accross. The site was built using Bake tool

Comment: Then it's probably just someone trying to access non-existing URLs, probably a search engine.

Comment: But the page on the browser is showing up with Internal Server error status code 500 and does not display the page

Comment: I also have Admin controller but not users controller. Not sure whether I need to have users controller as I didn't want to have login for it

Comment: In addition, Mysql was running at 150% CPU capacity not sure whether that had an impact on APC memory that Cake 2.1.1 uses by default if available. (APC is enabled in the server)

Comment: We also have Zend and Joomla sites at my work but it is always Cake that goes down often. Not sure whether Cake itself isn't stable enough or mod_rewrite or cache config is not set properly but those settings are pretty much out of the box from Cake initially and not being changed. Only thing that has changed I think is Route.php

Comment: I am getting something similar in Cake 2.0.something, pretty unpleasant when the log is recording a MissingControllerExceptions (ImagesController in my case) multiple times every second.

Comment: I also have this problem. Every day I find 20-30 times this error in my error.log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is adding following line to my `app/Config/routes.php` file. It redirects user to my main page.

```
Router::connect('/Assets', array('controller' => 'mainpages', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Answer (score 0):

we have similar problem with 2 services. both services write to the same cache. try to change prefix for cache in your config file